# Search a string in a text file, save a line that contains an item from the list and return NA if the item does not exist in the text file

Tags: python, regex, string, full-text-search

I have a list of items

```
ls=["John","Tanner",'Mary','Anna','25']
```

and a text file:

```
 V1 'John' 'blablablabla...'
 V2 'Anna' 'blablablabla...'
 V3 'Josh' 'blablablabla...'
 V4 'Mary' 'blablablabla...'
 V5 'Steven' 'blablablabla...'
```

I want to search each item of the list inside the text file, and save the line that contains the item.

```
var=[]
with open('C:/Maryam/example/test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for item in ls:
            if item in line:
                var.append(line)

var
```

The output already looks like:

```
["  V1 'John' 'blablablabla...'\n","  V2 'Anna' 'blablablabla...'\n",
"  V4 'Mary' 'blablablabla...'\n"]
```

But I expect to get something like this:

```
["  V1 'John' 'blablablabla...'\n", 'NA' , "  V2 'Anna' 'blablablabla...'\n",
"  V4 'Mary' 'blablablabla...'\n", 'NA']
```

I tried to generate 'NA' in the list but couldn't figure it out.
The reason I used 
    for line in file:
cause I want to save the whole line including specific string. Is there any way to use regular expressions, so I could get rid of the for loop on the lines and then save the whole line.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to use a dictionary instead of a list so you can store an entry for each element to search and the corresponding line (if any, `NA` otherwise):

```
# Initialize the result dictionary
result = {}
for name in ls:
    result[name] = 'NA'

# Process the file
with open('C:/Maryam/example/test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # For each line check if it contains a reserved keyword
        for name in result.keys():
            if name in line:
                result[name] = line

# Show result (key = name, value = line content)
result

# Show only the values (line contents)
result.values()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your code to check if anything was found on each different line:

```
var=[]
with open('C:/Maryam/example/test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        was_found=False
        for item in var:
            if item in line:
                var.append(line)
                was_found=True
        if not was_found:
            var.append("NA")
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'for-break-else' construction can be used,too:

```
for item in ls:
    if item in line:
        var.append(line)
        break
else:
        var.append("NA")
```